# Откуда приходят запросы к POP3 серверу?

Tags: smtp, pop3

Вчера провайдер открыл порт 25 чтобы мой smtp сервер мог отправлять письма сам, без помощи relay сервера. А сейчас посмотрел на логи сервера и они сильно увеличиваются каждую секунду. 
Приходят запросы на POP3 от каких то непонятных пользователей.
marie, jara, sepъlveda, rivera, morais, gonзalves, gonzбles, azevedo и еще кучи других. На что мой сервер отвечает, что требуется указывать полное email имя для авторизации или что пароль не подходит.

Из-за чего это происходит?

```
"TCPIP" 5104    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.655"   "TCP - 201.27.28.222 connected to 82.151.125.43:110."
"DEBUG" 5104    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.655"   "TCP connection started for session 7796"
"POP3D" 5104    7796    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.655"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK POP3"
"POP3D" 2452    7771    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.655"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"POP3D" 2452    7771    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.655"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK POP3 server saying goodbye..."
"DEBUG" 2452    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.655"   "Ending session 7771"
"POP3D" 5104    7786    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.655"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER molina"
"POP3D" 5104    7786    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.655"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK Send your password"
"POP3D" 2452    7778    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: PASS ***"
"POP3D" 4740    7773    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"POP3D" 4740    7773    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK POP3 server saying goodbye..."
"DEBUG" 1520    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "Ending session 7773"
"POP3D" 2452    7778    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: -ERR Invalid user name or password. Please use full email address as user name."
"POP3D" 5104    7785    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER arias"
"POP3D" 5104    7785    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK Send your password"
"POP3D" 2452    7777    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: PASS ***"
"POP3D" 2452    7777    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: -ERR Invalid user name or password. Please use full email address as user name."
"POP3D" 4740    7772    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"POP3D" 4740    7772    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK POP3 server saying goodbye..."
"DEBUG" 5104    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "Ending session 7772"
"DEBUG" 5104    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "Creating session 7798"
"TCPIP" 5104    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "TCP - 201.27.28.222 connected to 82.151.125.43:110."
"DEBUG" 5104    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "TCP connection started for session 7797"
"POP3D" 5104    7797    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK POP3"
"POP3D" 4740    7770    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"POP3D" 4740    7770    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK POP3 server saying goodbye..."
"DEBUG" 2452    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.670"   "Ending session 7770"
"POP3D" 4740    7787    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.686"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER aguirre"
"POP3D" 4740    7787    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.686"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK Send your password"
"POP3D" 2452    7784    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.702"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER rossi"
"POP3D" 2452    7784    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.702"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK Send your password"
"POP3D" 4740    7779    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.702"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: PASS ***"
"POP3D" 4740    7779    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.702"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: -ERR Invalid user name or password. Please use full email address as user name."
"POP3D" 2452    7788    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.717"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER ramz"
"POP3D" 2452    7788    "2016-02-06 05:29:12.717"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: +OK Send your password"


Включил TLS требование и через некоторое время запросы прекратились. Сейчас больше не приходят, вот последние строки логов.

"POP3D" 4232    10249   "2016-02-06 05:31:00.639"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER nъсez"
"POP3D" 4232    10249   "2016-02-06 05:31:00.639"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: -ERR STLS is required."
"POP3D" 4764    10250   "2016-02-06 05:31:00.686"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER hernбndez"
"POP3D" 4764    10250   "2016-02-06 05:31:00.686"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: -ERR STLS is required."
"POP3D" 1588    10251   "2016-02-06 05:31:00.702"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER gonzбles"
"POP3D" 1588    10251   "2016-02-06 05:31:00.702"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: -ERR STLS is required."
"POP3D" 4232    10252   "2016-02-06 05:31:00.733"   "201.27.28.222" "RECEIVED: USER gуnzalez"
"POP3D" 4232    10252   "2016-02-06 05:31:00.733"   "201.27.28.222" "SENT: -ERR STLS is required."



"TCPIP" 4232    "2016-02-06 05:32:06.983"   "TCP - 91.238.230.133 connected to 82.151.125.43:25."
"DEBUG" 4232    "2016-02-06 05:32:06.983"   "TCP connection started for session 10077"
"SMTPD" 4232    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:06.983"   "91.238.230.133"    "SENT: 220 smtp.site.ru"
"SMTPD" 3060    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:06.999"   "91.238.230.133"    "RECEIVED: EHLO User"
"SMTPD" 3060    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:06.999"   "91.238.230.133"    "SENT: 250-WIN-3OS58V5F8UK[nl]250-SIZE 20480000[nl]250-STARTTLS[nl]250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN[nl]250 HELP"
"SMTPD" 4784    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:07.014"   "91.238.230.133"    "RECEIVED: AUTH LOGIN"
"SMTPD" 4784    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:07.014"   "91.238.230.133"    "SENT: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6"
"SMTPD" 3432    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:07.030"   "91.238.230.133"    "RECEIVED: c3FsZXhlYw=="
"SMTPD" 3432    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:07.030"   "91.238.230.133"    "SENT: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6"
"SMTPD" 4784    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:07.045"   "91.238.230.133"    "RECEIVED: ***"
"SMTPD" 4784    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:07.045"   "91.238.230.133"    "SENT: 535 Authentication failed. Restarting authentication process."
"SMTPD" 4232    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:07.061"   "91.238.230.133"    "RECEIVED: QUIT"
"SMTPD" 4232    10077   "2016-02-06 05:32:07.061"   "91.238.230.133"    "SENT: 221 goodbye"
"DEBUG" 4784    "2016-02-06 05:32:07.061"   "Ending session 10077"
```

Comment: Непонятно. В тексте говорится об SMTP-сервере и 25 порте. А непосредственно вопрос и логи говорят о POP3 и 110 порте.

Comment: @Yaant 
Ну так есть smtp сервер и pop3(и imap) сервер. До этого smtp сервер работал через relay сервер провайдера и внешний порт 25 у провайдера был закрыт(а на vds моём был открыт), а сейчас сам отправляет письма другим. 
А боты подключаются к pop3.

Comment: @manking Я думаю провайдер кроме 25 открыл и 110 порт, а до этого он был закрыт и вы не видели постоянные попытки входа. Это в сегодняшнем интернете совершенно нормальная ситуация, на любой сервис постоянно кто нибудь коннектится пытается взломать и т.п. Если у вас нет снаружи pop3 клиентов, то закройте 110 порт фаерволом

Answer (score 5, accepted):

идет попытка взлома почтовика.

Comment: А зачем? 
И как понять откуда это идёт, это автомат или человек? 
Что сделать чтобы этого не было?

Comment: @manking Зачем? Чтобы потом с вашего почтаря спамить. Автомат или человек? Автомат, естественно! Всё это давно автоматизировано. Откуда? Из бот-сети, "размазанной" по всему миру. Что сделать, чтобы не было? Закрыть порт обратно.

Comment: @kff 
А вот я включил TLS и они больше не приходят. Значит c TLS они не будут пытаться взламывать или будут?

Comment: будут, не обязательно сегодня-завтра. Рекомендовать можно средства блокировки, типа fail2ban для Linux. Тогда попытки взлома минимизируются

Comment: @manking Опубликовав какой-либо сервис в Интернете, заранее будьте готовы к попыткам взлома. От Вас не отстанут **никогда**.

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте порт на нестандартный и посмотрите на результат. Например 110 на 9110. Конечно, пров должен открыть для вас этот порт.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?